# Filtering single unrouted IP with firewall VM

Tags: firewall, filtering, opnsense

I have virtualization hosts (*Proxmox*) running multiple VMs providing public services. I'm using a firewall appliance (*OPNsense*) to filter the traffic.
This works fine for a routed subnet, where the public IP is bound directly to the virtual network interface of the VM: I can set firewall rules to filter traffic based on port / source etc.

On one of the servers, I got one single additional public IP address from the hosting provider which is not part of a routed subnet. I got a **virtual MAC address** (virtual in terms of *not bound to a physical NIC*) and I can create a virtual network card for a VM with this MAC address which allows me to assign this IP directly to a VM which is attached to the public bridge.

Since I want to filter the traffic with my firewall appliance, I assigned an additional virtual NIC to the firewall VM. The VM that provides the service has a local / not routed IP address and is attached to a local bridge on a **LAN** port behind the firewall VM.
I can now use **destination NAT** rules to map specific ports for inbound traffic to the VM.

From my understanding, this would require me to add **source NAT** rules to make sure that outbound traffic from this VM gets the correct public IP address as its source. Is this correct?

I wonder if this is the best way to do this, or if there is a more transparent way where I don't have to deal with **DNAT** rules and all traffic facing the additional public IP would be directed 1:1 to the VM. Being able to do rule baed filtering would of course still be a requirement.